# What does this banner "to: me, new job! love: me!" mean?

Tags: discussion, advertising

I mean literally. Is there any sense in those wordings?

[image]

Comment: That's been annoying me for a while now, too.

Comment: his face... its not an appropriate face.

Comment: The real question is that the holiday season is over, why isn't this ad?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 If you find this ads annoying, you have clearly never seen the "Case of the Monday" one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's supposed to be the tag on a Christmas gift.

> to: me
>
> love (from): me

The gift that the guy is giving to himself is a new job.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Semicolon after "love" confused me. A coma will make it much clear.

Comment: Who tags their Christmas gifts with A4 sheets?

Comment: @DickLaurent FYI: It's a colon, not a semicolon.

Comment: Sure. Just a typo.

Answer (score 13):

> Dear Dick Laurent,
>
> Here's your new job which you got from using Careers 2.0
>
> Have a great Christmas.
>
> Love, Dick Laurent

Answer (score 10):

What?  That's not what it looks like on my machine!

[image]